# Calculator Paper Tape window not capturing any information

Tags: macos, applications

I am able to bring up the Paper Tape window, but no calculator entries end up on it. Any hints as to what might be the issue?

OS X El Capitan 10.11.5, Calculator v10.8 (123).

Answer (score 1):

The paper tape only records when pressing <kbd>=</kbd>. Press the equals button at the end of your calculation to record the calculation on the paper tape.

Comment: I realized that pressing `=` only works for standard and scientific mode. In programmer mode it doesn't seem to work even after pressing `=`. can you confirm that this is expected behavior?